# Spring Integration Groovy Script and SpEL

Tags: groovy, spring-integration, spring-el

I am trying to use Groovy script for a particular scenario in my spring-integration configuration. There are couple of errors that I'm not able to resolve or is beyond my understanding. Please excuse as I'm not very well versed in groovy scripting.

I have `spring-integration-groovy-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar` in my lib.

Below is my spring integration configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
   xmlns:int-groovy="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/groovy" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/groovy http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/groovy/spring-integration-groovy-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Works fine: Using service-activator and SpEL to call a java bean.method(params) -->
    <int:chain input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="responseChannel">
        <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-templates="BookingClassFilter_Template" result-transformer="resultToDOMSource" />
        <int:service-activator expression="@errorDetectionUtil.checkAndThrowExceptionOnError(#root)" />
    </int:chain>

    // Note: I want to replace the above int:chain with the below. Only the below section appears in my final configuration file deployed. The above int:chain is only as an example for Q&A.
    <!-- NOT WORKING: Using Groovy script -->
    <int:chain id="businessLayerResponse" input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="responseChannel">
        <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-templates="BookingClassFilter_Template" result-transformer="resultToDOMSource" />
        <int-groovy:script>
             def valBool = errorDetectionUtil.hasErrors(payload)
             if(valBool) throw new AppException(#root)     
             return #root    
        </int-groovy:script>
    </int:chain>
</beans>
```

Below is my Java class:

```
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;

@Component("errorDetectionUtil")
public class ErrorDetectionUtil {
    public boolean hasErrors(DOMSource domSource) {
        double countDbl = (double) errorsCounter.evaluate(domSource.getNode(), XPathConstants.NUMBER);
        return ((int) countDbl > 0)
    }
    public Message<?> checkAndThrowExceptionOnError(Message<?> message) throws AppException {
        if (hasErrors((DOMSource) message.getPayload())) {
            throw new AppException(message);
        }
        return message;
    }
}
// AppException extends org.springframework.integration.MessagingException
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Below is the exception stacktrace that I see when I start the app server.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#13': Cannot create inner bean 'businessLayerResponse$child#2.handler' of type [org.springframework.integration.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutingMessageProcessor] while setting bean property 'handlers' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'businessLayerResponse$child#2.handler': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'componentName' of bean class [org.springframework.integration.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutingMessageProcessor]: Bean property 'componentName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'businessLayerResponse$child#2.handler': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'componentName' of bean class [org.springframework.integration.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutingMessageProcessor]: Bean property 'componentName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'componentName' of bean class [org.springframework.integration.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutingMessageProcessor]: Bean property 'componentName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `<groovy:script>` isn't component per se. It can only reflect a bahavior of other EIP-specific component.

So, your `<service-activator>` will be there as well. But instead of `expression` you use `<script>`.

2. The `#root` variable is a part of SpEL and it is exactly `Message<?>`. For the scripts it is splitted to the `payload` and `headers` variables. And yes, you should use them already without `#`.

Right your `errorDetectionUtil` is available in the Groovy scripts since Spring Integration [3.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#groovy).

Comment: Thanks Artem! I made the implementation change using `<int-groovy:script>` inside `<int:service-activator>`. And yes I got rid of `componentName` exception. But I need to send the `Message<?>` object in the `AppException`. Is there a way by which I could set the `Message` Object while throwing `AppException`? For example `throw new AppException(#root)`

Comment: Glad to hear! If that's fine with you, it is good tone to accept answers.

Comment: I just now edited my previous comment. Could you please refer it again? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).copyHeaders(headers).build()` to create a `Message<?>` for your use-case based on the Groovy script state.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the guidelines. I'll update the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Following changes to my spring integration solved the issue:

```
<int:chain id="businessLayerResponse" input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="responseChannel">
    <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-templates="BookingClassFilter_Template" result-transformer="resultToDOMSource" />
    <int:service-activator>
       <int-groovy:script>
         def valBool = errorDetectionUtil.hasErrors(payload)
         def message = org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).copyHeaders(headers).build()
         if(java.lang.Boolean.valueOf(valBool)) { 
             throw new x.y.z.AppException(message) 
         }     
         return message
       </int-groovy:script>
    </int:service-activator>
</int:chain>
```

Note: Fully qualified java class names are required in the script.

Comment: ??? That's is bad tone to add your own answer, when it is based on another one...

Comment: Hi Artem, Sorry I did not understand initially what you meant by `good tone to accept answers` and `bad tone to add your own answer, when it is based on another one`. Is there any option in the post that I am missing to accept a comment as an answer? I will make necessary changes, it will be a guideline for me henceforth.

Comment: No problem! That's just routine, but I like to participate in this gambling :-). You should just follow with http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Ha ha ha !! Finally got it. Yet another answer. Thanks :)